# How should you get post data on a custom rendered ASP.net webforms control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

WebForms does lots of work for you, from creating the HTML text to be sent, to reading the response data back into the correct server side controls.

However when you want total control over the HTML generated, or improve the speed of the rendering, you need to inherit WebControl and override the Render method.  That's great for generating the HTML, but if a user makes any changes to the state of your new control in the browser, how can you get that information back to deal with it within your control?

I am aware that MVC may be a better framework if you're after this level of control, I would just like to know if it's reasonably achievable in webforms.

Comment: what do  you mean by `user makes any changes to the state of your new control in the browser`?

Comment: If you're using a normal user control, and you make a change to for example a radio group item, webforms track that change in the browser, and update the respective server component.

Comment: as far I know, webforms doesn't track those changes..instead a request will be sent(or posted back) from the browser to server where these changes can be identified.. and I don't think you will have any issues with whatever the method you have stated.. 
Have you tried anything or just predicting the things?..

Comment: Are you saying that you just need to check the Request.Form["..."] value, and then set a variable within the custom control which could then be used within the aspx file?

Comment: exactly.. and to some extent VIEWSTATE may also help you in subsequent rendering..

Comment: also go through [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)